# Displaying an array by using pointer techniques

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I want to display the contents of an array with type double that has a length of 5 without using the [ ] indexing . I can only use a for loop and pointer techniques.

How can you achieve that ? 
Can anyone give me a brief explanation of pointers as I have no idea how to use them exactly ?

Comment: Have you tried anything or even did a google research? There is a ton of documentation about pointers out there. If you want a detailled answer, please ask a detailed question. See [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more :)

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/q/6814533/1741542?

Comment: Firstly you should read something about pointers, then you should study pointer arithmetic, that's what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

The array indexing operator is a shorthand for hiding pointer arithmetic.

So if you have an array like this:

```
double a[5];
```

Instead of using this expression:

```
a[1]
```

You can use this:

```
*(a + 1)
```